# c shell environment variable error: "Bad : modifier in $"

Tags: environment-variables, tcsh

I am using tcsh and define an environmental variable as follows:

```
setenv mycomp myusername@my.computer.com
```

so that when I need to copy files from the remote my.computer.com, I type the following:

```
scp $mycomp:sourcepath destpath
```

But when I do this, I get the following error: "Bad : modifier in $ (m)." where (m) is the first character after the colon.

What is this error telling me, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable expansion with a colon after it treats the letters after the colon as modifiers.

For example, `$dir:h` means expand `$dir` with the `h` modifier.  `h` means head, i.e. all but the last part of the path.

```
% set dir=/home/user
% echo $dir:h
/home
```

All the info is in the tcsh(1) man page:

```
History substitution

   ...

   The word or words in a history reference  can  be  edited,  or  ‘‘modi-
   fied’’,  by following it with one or more modifiers, each preceded by a
   ‘:’:

       h       Remove a trailing pathname component, leaving the head.
       t       Remove all leading pathname components, leaving the tail.
       r       Remove a filename extension ‘.xxx’, leaving the root  name.
       e       Remove all but the extension.
       u       Uppercase the first lowercase letter.
       l       Lowercase the first uppercase letter.
       s/l/r/  Substitute  l  for  r.
       ...


Variable substitution

   ...

   The ‘:’ modifiers described  under  History  substitution,  except  for
   ‘:p’,  can be applied to the substitutions above.
```

You can avoid the modifier by wrapping the variable name in braces, e.g.

```
scp ${mycomp}:sourcepath destpath
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think that if I want to avoid using {}, then my solution is to switch to the bash shell :).

Comment: @Marshall: There are many reasons to prefer Bash over tcsh, but be aware that there are times when you need to use curly braces with variable names in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a tcsh environment to test this out I'd guess that when the shell is looking for your environment variable, it is not splitting out on the : and looking for $mycomp:sourcepath as the whole variable name.

I would try aliasing out your scp command.

Comment: Thanks, ${mycomp}:sourcepath destpath works, so that must be correct. Is using {} the only way to get it to work?

Comment: @Marshall: You can use quotes: `$"mycomp":sourcepath`.